# Can bash case statements cascade?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
case $level in
    3)
        echo "Level Three"

    2)
        echo "Level Two"

    1)
        echo "Level one"
        ;;
esac
```

where if $level = 3, it would output

```
Level Three
Level Two
Level One
```

while if $level = 1, it would output only

```
Level One
```

But when I try it, I get the error `syntax error near unexpected token ')'` because I didn't include the `;;`.

Every other language I know of allows this, is there a way to do it in bash? Some sort of keyword that means "now go on and do the next case as if it matched"?

Comment: If every language you know allows this, you need to learn languages other than C and its imitators. Fallthrough in case statements are a historical design accident in C that somehow survived in more principled languages.

Comment: @GillesSO-stopbeingevil Not true. Fallthrough is a useful feature, and its harmfulness is just a widespread myth. Many programmers complain about _implicit_ fallthrough, saying it's a tragedy that a non-fallthroughing `case` requires an explicit `break`; ridiculous. Moreover, the very few reasons that I did see, because "it's easy to forget the `break`" is plain wrong, and because "I don't like it" is irrational.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to use `;&` instead of `;;` to get a fall-through behavior:

```
#! /bin/bash
foo() {
    case "$1" in
        3)
            echo "Level Three"
            ;&
        2)
            echo "Level Two"
            ;&
        1)
            echo "Level One"
            ;;
        a)
            echo "Level a"
            ;&
        b)
            echo "Level b"
            ;&
        c)
            echo "Level c"
            ;;
    esac
}
echo 3:
foo 3
echo 2:
foo 2
echo a:
foo a
```

```
3:
Level Three
Level Two
Level one
2:
Level Two
Level one
a:
Level a
Level b
Level c
```

See the [Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) section of the bash documentation.

The other special marker is `;;&`, which:

> causes the shell to test the patterns in the next clause, if any, and execute any associated command-list on a successful match.

`;;` is always final, no further patterns are tested.

```
#! /bin/bash

foo() {
    case "$1" in
        *3*)
            echo "Level Three"
            ;;&
        *2*)
            echo "Level Two"
            ;;&
        *1*)
            echo "Level One"
            ;;&
    esac
}

echo 12:
foo 12
echo 13:
foo 13
echo 23:
foo 23
```

```
12:
Level Two
Level One
13:
Level Three
Level One
23:
Level Three
Level Two
```

Comment: Portability note: that syntax is not POSIX. It comes from `ksh` and is available in `ksh`, `bash` (since 4.0, 2009) and `zsh` (since 3.1.2, 1997). `;;&` is bash-specific.

Comment: Also note that the `zsh` equivalent of `bash`'s `;;&` is `;|` (added in 4.3.3, 2007).

Comment: Not to confuse with `&|`, which is completely unrelated to this. `;)` (and that was just a blink emoticon... for now)

Comment: Yep, it'd be nice to have POSIX syntax (for `dash`).

Comment: The POSIX way to do it (especially to target BSD shells) would be to use one `case` (or `if`) statement per condition.